# chain $.when, .then(), .done()

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred

I would like to perform an ajax request, and when it is done, append the returned HTML to a div, and once that data is appended, perform another ajax request that will, in turn, add content to the HTML that was appended previously. But apparently I have a some syntax errors. Am I chaining `then()` and `done()` incorrectly?

```
$.when(append_line_item())
 .then(function (line_item_data) {
    $('#line_items').append(line_item_data)}
  .done(populateMainProductsSelect())
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're over-thinking it, you don't need `$.when` or `$.then` in this case.

```
// assuming append_line_item() returns a promise object
append_line_item().done(function(line_item_data){
    $('#line_items').append(line_item_data);
    populateMainProductsSelect();
});
```

The syntax error happens here:

```
 done(populateMainProductsSelect())
```

you just need to remove the `()`

```
 done(populateMainProductsSelect)
```

Comment: in particular, the appending operation is synchronous, not async, so you can just call the second AJAX function immediately after the `.append()`.

Comment: Then yes, it's a promise object. jqXHR objects have a .promise method which returns a promise object

Comment: It is automatically generated, you do not need to call `.promise` yourself, `$.when` will do that.

Comment: @Alnitak Isn't that what's being done in Kevin's answer. I don't understand the difference(?) Thank you.

Comment: @thomas yes, my note was just a clarification

Comment: But you've removed the `$.when` in your solution.

Comment: `$.when()` is only required if you want to synchronise two or more promises, and get a _new_ promise when both (all) of them are resolved.

Comment: Yes, because the jqXHR object itself implements the same methods as a promise object, allowing you to use it as one directly. $.when when passed in a single promise object will return that promise object directly, so using `$.when($.get(...))` is (mostly?) equivalent to `$.get(...)`

Comment: @KevinB the difference between the two is that the result of `$.when($.get(...))` is _only_ a promise and no longer has the remaining jqXHR properties attached.

Comment: @Alnitak What jqXHR properties are you referring to the loss of? :/